# Laravel get array in blade with such 'bns:OrderId' names in it?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I get a array from a external company to handle in my laravel application

The incoming json has names like 'bns:OrderId' in it ?

blade give a error when i try to access     {{ $order->bns:OrderId }}

How can i handle this??

Controller :

```
    public function getBolOrders()
{
    // or live API: https://plazaapi.bol.com
    $url = 'https://test-plazaapi.bol.com';
    $uri = '/services/rest/orders/v1/open';

    // your public key
    $public_key = '<public key>';

    //your private key
    $private_key = '<private key>';

    $port = 443;
    $contenttype = 'application/xml';
    $date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
    $httpmethod = 'GET';

    $signature_string = $httpmethod . "\n\n";
    $signature_string .= $contenttype . "\n";
    $signature_string .= $date."\n";
    $signature_string .= "x-bol-date:" . $date . "\n";
    $signature_string .= $uri;
    $signature = $public_key.':'.base64_encode(hash_hmac('SHA256', $signature_string, $private_key, true));

    // Setup CURL (One can also opt to use sockets or http libraries, but CURL is a versatile, widespread solution)
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: ".$contenttype, "X-BOL-Date:".$date, "X-BOL-Authorization: ".$signature));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$uri);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $orders = fopen("orders.xml", "w");
    fwrite($orders, $result);
    fclose($orders);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
       print_r(curl_errno($ch), true);
    }
// Clean up after ourselves
    curl_close($ch);
// Convert XML TO JSON
    $xmlNode = simplexml_load_file('orders.xml');
    $arrayData = xmlToArray($xmlNode);
    $OpenOrder = $arrayData['OpenOrders']['bns:OpenOrder'];
//    dd($OpenOrder);
// Goto view
    return view('bol.open-orders', compact('OpenOrder'));
}
```

dd from array :

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
   "bns:OrderId" => "123"
   "bns:DateTimeCustomer" => "2016-11-07T15:20:08.904"
   "bns:DateTimeDropShipper" => "2016-11-07T15:20:08.904"
   "bns:Paid" => "true"
   "bns:Buyer" => array:2 [▶]
   "bns:OpenOrderItems" => array:1 [▶]
 ]
 1 => array:6 [▼
   "bns:OrderId" => "321"
   "bns:DateTimeCustomer" => "2016-11-07T15:20:08.904"
   "bns:DateTimeDropShipper" => "2016-11-07T15:20:08.904"
   "bns:Paid" => "false"
   "bns:Buyer" => array:2 [▶]
   "bns:OpenOrderItems" => array:1 [▶]
   ]
]
```

Example blade template :

```
@foreach ($OpenOrder as $order)
    {{ $order->bns:OrderId }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: provide your controller and full query. show me the `dd($OpenOrder);` data.

Comment: Changed the question text

Comment: please don't share your credentials, ex: public and privat key in public area.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query returns the collection of `arrays` values not an `Object`. use this `{{ $order["bns:OrderId"] }}` instead of this `{{ $order->bns:OrderId }}`.

Try this:

```
@foreach ($OpenOrder as $order)
    {{ $order["bns:OrderId"] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: @RudiWerner Happy to help :)